# Google Dopamine

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I was importing some dopamine dependencies, and I got an error saying No module named DopamineKit found. I then installed it separately using the code: !pip install dopaminekit. It installed dopaminekit module, but I am still getting a similar error. I have attached my code, and error below. I would really appreciate, if anyone is able to help me through this.

```
import numpy as np
import os
from dopamine.agents.dqn import dqn_agent
from dopamine.atari import run_experiment
from dopamine.colab import utils as utils_colab
from absl import flags

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-c5b224b9c6df> in <module>()
  1 import numpy as np
  2 import os
----> 3 from dopamine.agents.dqn import dqn_agent
  4 from dopamine.atari import run_experiment
  5 from dopamine.colab import utils as utils_colab

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dopamine/__init__.py in <module>()
  3 ## This is solely used to import the class DopamineKit
  4 
----> 5 from dopaminekit import DopamineKit

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/dopaminekit/__init__.py in <module>()
  3 ## This is solely used to import the class DopamineKit
  4 
----> 5 from dopaminekit import DopamineKit

ImportError: cannot import name 'DopamineKit'
```

Comment: dopaminekit is a completely different thing that also happens to use the name "dopamine". Also, even with dopaminekit, that `dopaminekit` folder should not exist, so it looks like you may have screwed up your environment further.

Comment: I changed from google colabs to JuPyter Notebook, but it is still showing me the exact same problem. Do I clear the directory, and reinstall all the dependencies? What would you suggest me to fix this problem?